# Issue with rest-api plugin and missing gson view

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I've a rest-api-plugin in grails 3.3.9 that has a couple of gson views for  rendering the controller methods. When I include this plugin in another new grails project either the gson views are not called at all or they cannot be found (depending on wether I am using render/respond and specifiying the view).

I've tried specifying plugin in the render call but this doesn't help. I can see the gson files in the included plugin. In the new rest-api profile project, when the view is specified in the plugin it looks like DefaultGroovyPageLocator is trying to find something like .json.gsp and nothing is looking for .gson (not sure if something should be?).

Any ideas as to how I might sort this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> ...DefaultGroovyPageLocator is trying to find something like .json.gsp and nothing is looking for .gson

If that is true that nothing is looking for `.gson`, that is a bug.  Please report an issue at https://github.com/grails/grails-views/issues and we can investigate.  Thanks.